# PHP: How to turn an array into a StdClass object?

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function that will do this automatically?

```
if (is_array($array)) {
    $obj = new StdClass();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val){
        $obj->$key = $val;
    }
    $array = $obj;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not just cast it?

```
$myObj = (object) array("name" => "Jonathan");
print $myObj->name; // Jonathan
```

If it's multidimensional, Richard Castera provides the following solution on [his blog](http://www.richardcastera.com/2009/07/06/php-convert-array-to-object-with-stdclass/):

```
function arrayToObject($array) {
  if(!is_array($array)) {
    return $array;
  }
  $object = new stdClass();
    if (is_array($array) && count($array) > 0) {
      foreach ($array as $name=>$value) {
        $name = strtolower(trim($name));
          if (!empty($name)) {
            $object->$name = arrayToObject($value);
          }
      }
      return $object; 
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answers are often simplest +1

Answer (score 3):

If it's a one-dimensional array, a cast should work:

```
$obj = (object)$array;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
if (is_array($array)) {
$obj = new StdClass();
foreach ($array as $key => $val){

    $key = str_replace("-","_",$key) 

    $obj->$key = $val;
}
$array = $obj;
}
```

make sure that str_replace is there as '-' is not allowed within variable names in php, as well as:

Naming Rules for Variables

```
* A variable name must start with a letter or an underscore "_"
* A variable name can only contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and _ )
* A variable name should not contain spaces. If a variable name is more than one word, it should be separated with an underscore ($my_string), or with capitalization ($myString)
```

So, since these are permitted in arrays, if any of them comes in the $key from the array you are converting, you will have nasty errors.