# How do I fill an object in PHP from an Array

Tags: php

Suppose I have:

```
class A{
 public $one;
 public $two;
}
```

and an array with values:

```
array('one' => 234, 'two' => 2)
```

is there a way to have an instance of A filled with the right values from the array automatically?

Comment: Define *automatically*. Does the instance of `A` already exists or must it be created? If yes, with or without calling the constructor of that instance?

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP: How to turn an array into a StdClass object]? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885160/php-how-to-turn-an-array-into-a-stdclass-object

Comment: @Rob2211: I searched as well, but `A` ain't `StdClass`.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed StdClass was similar to Java's `Object`, it's not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to write yourself a function for that. PHP has [`get_object_vars`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/get_object_vars) but no *set* counterpart:

```
function set_object_vars($object, array $vars) {
    $has = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach ($has as $name => $oldValue) {
        $object->$name = isset($vars[$name]) ? $vars[$name] : NULL;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$a = new A();
$vars = array('one' => 234, 'two' => 2);
set_object_vars($a, $vars);
```

Comment: Brilliant! What would I need to change to get the same effect for another 2 dimension steps? $object['x']['y']['z'];

Comment: NB This **DOES NOT REVEAL** `PROTECTED` and `PRIVATE` variables if used as a normal function. As 95% of all variables I use are protected for obvious reasons this does not work. (Wasted 20 mins on this.) Tried putting it in the class but then lots of `array_key_exists` needs 2 param warnings and no result so gave up. Might be usable with @menacingly suggestion but too clever for me so off to fudge it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow for bulk-setting of attributes, you can also store them as a property.  It allows you to encapsulate within the class a little better.

```
class A{
  protected $attributes = array();
  function setAttributes($attributes){
    $this->attributes = $attributes;
  }

  public function __get($key){
    return $this->attributes[$key];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

@hakre version is quite good, but dangerous (suppose an **id** or password is in thoses props).

I would change the default behavior to that:

```
function set_object_vars($object, array $vars) {
    $has = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach ($has as $name => $oldValue) {        
        array_key_exists($name, $vars) ?  $object->$name =$vars[$name] : NULL;
    }
}
```

here, the previous properties that are not in the $vars array are not affected.
and if you want to set a prop to null **on purpose**, you can.

Comment: array_key_exists() function has two params - key & search.

Comment: yes, right, I suppose I wrote it on the fly without testing. It then shall be:   array_key_exists($name, $vars)

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is.

You *could* use a pass thru method.

For example:

```
class A {
    public $one, $tow;
    function __construct($values) {
        $this->one = $values['one'] ?: null;
        $this->two = $values['two'] ?: null;
    }
}

$a = new A(array('one' => 234, 'two' => 2));
```

Comment: @Rob2211 true, but it is the best that I can think of.